# How to add KVO to synchronized class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, kvocontroller

In my app I have the `Restaurant` class that you can see below. I'd like to attach a `KVOController` to it. But I'm having no luck. When I attach it with the code below, it crashes.

```
FBKVOController *KVOController = [FBKVOController controllerWithObserver:self];
    self.KVOController = KVOController;

    [self.KVOController observe:self keyPath:@"[Restaurant current].name.asString" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial|NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew block:^(id observer, id object, NSDictionary *change) {
        DDLogDebug(@"Restaurant changed");
    }];
```

What's the best way to add KVO to a class like this?

```
@implementation Restaurant

static Restaurant *current = nil;

+ (Restaurant *)current {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (current == nil) {            
            current = [[Restaurant alloc] initWithId:0];
        }
    }
    return current;
}

- (id)initWithId:(NSInteger)number {
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        ...
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not `@synchronized`. There are several issues with your code:

- Do you want to observe when the current restaurant changes? Or when the current restaurant's name changes (without `+[Restaurant current]` pointing to a different restaurant instance). Or any kind of name change, whether triggered by a change of `current` or a change of `name`?

  - Depending on the answer, you'll either want to observe `observe:[Restaurant class]` or `observe:[Restaurant instance]`, but definitely not `observe:self` (unless you're setting this up inside the `Restaurant` class implementation, in which case `[self class]` would be an alternative to `[Restaurant class]`).
  - For any change to be observable, you must ensure that the class is implemented in a [KVO-compliant](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE) way. This goes both for changes to `+[Restaurant current]` as well as for changes to `-[Restaurant name]`, depending on what you want to be able to observe.
- `[Restaurant current].name.asString` is not a valid key path. Valid key paths may only contain property names (ASCII, begin with a lowercase letter, no whitespace) and dots to separate them (see [Key-value coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KeyValueCoding.html) for details). Once you're telling the KVOController to `observe:[Restaurant class]`, all that remains for the key path is `current.name.asString`.
- What is `name` if not a string? Do you really need to convert it to a string for observing it? If your intention is to watch for name changes, observing `current.name` is probably sufficient.

You'll likely end up with one of the following two options:

```
FBKVOController *kvoController = [FBKVOController controllerWithObserver:self];
[kvoController observe:[Restaurant class] keyPath:@"current.name" ...];`
// or
[kvoController observe:[Restaurant current] keyPath:@"name" ...];`
```

And again, for any changes to be observable, they need to be [KVO-compliant](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE).